# Can I override a class function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript but I have some experience of Javascript.

I am trying to override a method in a class that I can't change. Here it is working in Javascript:

```
var wijmo;
(function (wijmo) {
    'use strict';
    var existingFormatNumber = wijmo.Globalize.formatNumber;

    wijmo.Globalize.formatNumber = function (value, format, trim) {

        //do some new stuff here
        //then call the existing format number method

        return existingFormatNumber(value, format, trim);
    }
})(wijmo || (wijmo = {}));
```

I suppose the requirement is that I want any code to call the new function rather than the old (including stuff that hasn't been written by me).

Is there a way to do this or is this too naughty for Typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code will work as is in TypeScript, but here's a version that uses TypeScript's `namespace` keyword.

```
namespace wijmo {
    'use strict';

    var existingFormatNumber = wijmo.Globalize.formatNumber;

    wijmo.Globalize.formatNumber = function (value, format, trim) {

        //do some new stuff here
        //then call the existing format number method

        return existingFormatNumber(value, format, trim);
    }
}
```

However, TypeScript won't understand what `wijmo.Globalize.formatNumber` is. So it needs to be declared.

```
declare namespace wijmo.Globalize {
    export function formatNumber(value: any, format: any, trim: any);
}
```

Comment: thanks very much. No need for me to declare formatNumber - it's written in typescript.